# Strange conjugation of 煎る ー is it an irregular verb?

Tags: grammar, words, conjugations, irregularities-exceptions

[I looked up いる in the OJAD Pitch Accent Dictionary](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/search/index/sortprefix:accent/narabi1:kata_asc/narabi2:accent_asc/narabi3:mola_asc/yure:visible/curve:invisible/details:invisible/limit:20/word:%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B), which shows every verb conjugation and the pitch accent of each conjugation. 要る and 入る, and 居る and 射る were conjugated as I would have expected, as godan and ichidan verbs respectvely (listed as １グループの動詞 and ２グループの動詞).

However I was surprised by the conjugation of 煎る, listed as ichidan:

- 煎る・煎ります・煎って・煎った・ 煎ろう were all conjugated like a godan verb,
- 煎ない・煎なかった・煎させる were all conjugated like an ichidan verb, and
- 煎りろ, the imperative form, is just weird.

Is this just a mistake in the dictionary, or is 煎る an irregular verb? If it is, what pattern does it follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other dictionaries say 煎る is godan, and I believe this is a mistake of this site. Scrambled egg is [いりたまご](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%82%92%E3%82%8A%E5%8D%B5), not いたまご.

Thus its negative form should be 煎らない, although admittedly this conjugation is uncommon, and even native speakers may sometimes make a mistake and say 煎ない.